# How to multiply matrices n-times?

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

I came across a problem. I am trying to do some matrix operations and I have to multiply several matrices, which are contained in one list, but the number of matrices is a variable that can be chosen at the beginning of the code.

Is there an efficient way of multiplying multiple matrices with each other instead of writing it n times like in

```
M.append(np.linalg.multi_dot([a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]]))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can we see some relevant code?

Comment: use a for loop?

Comment: I tried looping, but how do u multiply the (n+1)th matrix to the result A *B in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

This is what `multi_dot` is for. Read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html).

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((10000, 100))
B = np.random.random((100, 1000))
C = np.random.random((1000, 5))
D = np.random.random((5, 333))

list_of_arrays = [A, B, C, D]

# the actual dot multiplication
output = np.linalg.multi_dot(list_of_arrays)
output.shape
```

```
(10000, 333)
```

---

Doing this as a `for loop` -

```
list_of_arrays = [A, B, C, D]

output = A
for i in list_of_arrays[1:]:
    output = output@i        # @= operator not supported yet :(
    
output.shape
```

```
(10000, 333)
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried the @= operation and it sadly did not work :p Now it works :)

Comment: glad to help, the @= looks like a cool emoji, would love to have it in python.